# flutter: what should I test in a page?

Tags: flutter, testing

I have finished all the pages and I want to start testing. I have read the docs about [unit test](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction). Also, I learned the `test_widget.dart` in an init flutter project. (the counter project you must know).  But when come to my own pages, for example, a `login page`, I have little idea about what should I test. Could you please give me some tips?

Comment: you start coding first. Code based on the design, get the output you required. If there is an error in your program, then only you debug. `I have little idea about what should I test.` If you mean you wanted to test whether your IDE is working fine with flutter and dart plugin, you can check the error log. It will show error when you try to run your program. Again, start coding and worry less.

Comment: @TryHarder Thanks for your reply. Actually, I complete all the pages and I haven't found any obvious error or bug. But it seems that I should add `test code` to guarantee the app is good, it's required. So my question is what aspects should I test in the test code?